# Centre an Icon within a div - Bootstrap 3 & Font Awesome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple bootstrap grid with a row displaying some text in one column and a stacked font-awesome icon set in another column. The issue I'm having is the **icon-set is not vertically aligned in the middle of the div, as the text is**. As you can see the icon is more aligned to the top of the div. Is there a way to center align this?

I've created a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sjehvfvj/) and re-posted the code below:

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row posted-content">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <h4 class="text-primary pull-left">Hey, this is some text</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 comment-count pull-right">
      <a class="fa-stack comment-action">
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-fw fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">5</i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.posted-content {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-width: 1140px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I've tried playing with vertical-align but to no avail. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: This is more complex that you might think. The problem is that the columns are not the same height....if you want vertical alignment of content in different columns you first have to make them the same height. Oh, and `vertical-align` on works on inline elements in the same parent..

Comment: good point about the vertical-align parent issue, noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row posted-content centered-vertically">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <h4 class="text-primary pull-left">Hey, this is some text ghssd fjkflsdj sdfkkl;asdk</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 comment-count pull-right">
      <a class="fa-stack comment-action">
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-fw fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">5</i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-fluid .centered-vertically{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/BKUM/sjehvfvj/3/)

Comment: fantastic - this worked perfect. Had not considered using flex, nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little Workaround with flexbox:

```
.posted-content {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-width: 1140px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.posted-content:before,.posted-content:after{
  display:none;
}

.comment-action {
  color: #79858A;
}

.comment-count>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.comment-count>a:hover {
  color: #d9534f !important;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pob5uuvq/)

Comment: works just as well as the below, only happened to read BKMs answer first hence why he got the green tick :)